# How do I fill my html canvas up with a complete image instead of only half an image using rgba pixeldata?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

I am drawing an image into my canvas using an array of rgba pixel values obtained from an image and drawn using ctx.fillrect(x,y,1,1) per pixel on the cnavas, yet it is only filling up the canvas with half the image from top to bottom.

The drawn image needs to fill up the entire canvas with the entire image.

[image: halfway canvas image]

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
      <script src='app.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <img src="coins.png" id="myImage">
      <br>
      <button type="button" onclick="run();">Run</button>
      <br>
      <div id='canvasContainer' style='border:1px solid #333;'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
// Run Function...
function run() {
  // Step 1: Get Image Data (width, height, pixels) ------------------------ Done.
  var data = getImageData();

  // Step 2: Optimize Data
  var optimizedData = optimizeData(data);

  // Step 3: Let Client Download Optimized Data and Generate Canvas Object
  generateCanvasObject(optimizedData);
}

// Returns a data object containing width, height and a pixel data array (r,g,b,a)
function getImageData() {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var img = document.getElementById('myImage');

  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,img.naturalWidth,img.naturalHeight);

  var data = {};
  data.width = imgData.width;
  data.height = imgData.height;
  data.pixelData = imgData.data;

  return data;
}

// Return optimized data from unoptimized data object
function optimizeData(data) {
  // Needs work...

  return data;
}

// Returns canvas object from optimized data
function generateCanvasObject(optimizedData) {
  // Optimized Data
  var pixelData = optimizedData.pixelData;

  // Canvas Object
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = optimizedData.width;
  canvas.height = optimizedData.height;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  // Draw to Context...
  var i = 0;
  for (var y=0; y < optimizedData.height; y++) {
    for (var x=0; x < optimizedData.width; x++) {
      var r = pixelData[i];
      var g = pixelData[i+1];
      var b = pixelData[i+2];
      var a = pixelData[i+3];

      ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + "," + (a/255) + ")";
      ctx.fillRect(x,y,1,1);

      i+=4
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('canvasContainer').appendChild(canvas);
}
```

Comment: Where is your `run()` function and the optimizedData?

Comment: I've updated my question with more code for context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the canvas you're creating inside getImageData() has a size of 300x150 pixels - it's default. It's size must match the size of the image you want to draw onto.

```
function getImageData() {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var img = document.getElementById('myImage');
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
  var data = {};
  data.width = imgData.width;
  data.height = imgData.height;
  data.pixelData = imgData.data;

  return data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you obscure, this is the correct answer, your help is well appreciated!